# Tomcat undeploys apps after ssh session or after few hours.

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, war

Tomcat is still running, I can access the tomcat homepage. However, every few hours tomcat undeploys the wars. No idea why. the apps show a blank white page.

Sometimes, when I end the ssh session the wars undeploy as well. However, ssh'ing into server auto redeploys all wars without needing to restart tomcat.

Catalina.out shows this at time of undeployment.

```
Aug 13, 2014 7:58:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/tapestry/apache-tomcat-7.0.55/webapps/host-manager has finished in 44 ms
Aug 13, 2014 8:01:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig undeploy
INFO: Undeploying context [/tapestry]
Aug 13, 2014 8:01:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
Aug 13, 2014 8:01:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 13, 2014 8:01:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
```

Comment: looks like someone is logging into host-manager and unloading your apps.

Comment: how can i further look into this? I am the only one who uses this server.

Comment: did you access host-manager around 7:58?  Check your access logs

Comment: I did not. But the undeployment occurred at 8:01. This issue is driving me nuts. It all started recently when we had a power outage and our servers went down. After coming back up I keep having this issue. Not sure if the outage has anything to do with it. Ive tried reinstalling tomcat and java as a precaution, but still no luck.

Comment: I would change your passwords for the tomcat manager

Comment: but do you find it bizarre that tomcat undeploys wars after i end ssh session, but as soon as I ssh in again the wars are deployed. I don't need to restart tomcat, it just auto deploys again.

Comment: anything in your .bashrc files?

Comment: I added these to lines at the end of bashrc. I didnt touch anything else. 

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
export CATALINA_HOME=/home/tapestry/apache-tomcat-7.0.55

Comment: very bizarre - good luck

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate you trying to help out.